# 'Anonymous function' when using jQuery AJAX method to send localstorage value server-side

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to send a `localStorage` value to the server-side using an AJAX request, however I'm unable to get it working properly. Based on other stack questions I've tried several options (with and without `datatype` declaration, with and without `JSON.stringify`, etc.). I have not been able to find an example fitting my exact needs.

With the code below I keep getting an error 500 and the message that `$.ajax` is an anonymous function. Hopefully someone is able to find the error. Thanks in advance!

```js
localStorage.setItem("PID","01234");
var data = localStorage.getItem("PID");

$.ajax({
    url: "../SaveData.aspx/SaveData",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { 
        alert(result.d); // I want it to return the PID value
    }, 
    error: function (err) { 
        alert("This does not work"); 
    }
});
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(UserData data)
{
    return "PID = " + data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow the default C# MVC ModelBinder to do its work for you the keys of the object you send in the AJAX request must match the property names of your `UserData` class. For example:

```
public class UserData {
    public string PID { get; set; }
}
```

Also note that your current WebMethod is returning a string, not JSON, so would need amending as well:

```
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod]
public static object SaveData(UserData data)
{
    return new { d = data };
}
```

Finally you would need to create an object in JS with the `PID` property set to the required value:

```
localStorage.setItem("PID","01234");
var data = {
    PID: localStorage.getItem("PID") // The keys here should match the request class
}

$.ajax({
    url: "../SaveData.aspx/SaveData",
    type: "POST",
    data: data, // Note JSON.stringify is not needed
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { 
        alert(result.d); // the key here matches those of the response class
    }, 
    error: function (err) { 
        alert("This does not work"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Rory. Very helpful. I'll try it out and let you know how it works out. Thanks again!